# Unwanted Multiple KeyDown Events triggered on single keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So basically what I need to do is detect a keydown event of spacebar and hence perform some logic based on it in my javascript file.

So as you can see in my html, that there is a button "compose" on clicking which the message-container is displayed.

Now I need to implement Gmail like feature of converting the mail ids in recipients as tags but in my case a valid mail-id will be converted to a tag as soon as a space-bar is pressed, i.e, the string before the space bar will be checked for valid email-id.

So i've written the on-click function of the recipient container and the keydown function for spacebar.

Now here comes the problem. When the page is loaded for the first time, it works perfectly fine. I click inside the recipient box and as soon as i hit space bar, "spacebar pressed" gets printed on the browser console one time for one key down.

Now if I hide this message-container div by clicking the "close" button, and then again show the message-container div by clicking the "compose" button, and then when i click in the recipients box, it fires two keydown events for spacebar i.e., "spacebar pressed" will be printed twice.

And consequently, if i again close and reopen the box and click again, it will print "spacebar pressed" three times for every keydown of spacebar.

So is it something related to binding and unbinding of events or something else? Coz i have gone through similar links in which the key down event was getting binding again and again, but could really figure out how I would like kill the event on clicking of "close" button.

Here is html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ZMail</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fonts.css" />  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />  

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h2>ZMail</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="body-container">
        <button type="button" class="compose-button" id="compose-button">Compose</button>
        <div class="message-container" id="message-container">
            <div class="compose-form-header">
                <p> New Message </p>
                <button type="button" class="close-button" id="close-button">x</button>
            </div>
            <form id="compose-form" method="POST" action="">
                <div class="recipient-container" id="recipient-container">
                    <div class="to-box" id="to-box">
                        <p>To</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-elements-container" id="input-elements-container">
                        <input type="text" id="recipient-box" name="recipients" placeholder="Recipients">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="text" id="subject-box" name="subject" placeholder="Subject">
                <textarea form="compose-form" id="message-text-box" name="message-text" ></textarea>
                <div class="send-button-container">
                    <button type="submit" class="send-mail-button" id="send-mail-button">Send</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And here is the JS

```
var contacts = ['ankush.rgv@gmail.com']

$(document).on('ready', function(){

    $("#message-container").hide();
    $("#to-box").hide();

    $("#compose-button").click(function (event) {
        if($("#message-container").is(':hidden')){
            $(function() {
                $("#recipient-box" ).autocomplete({
                   source: contacts
                });
            });
            $("#message-container").show();
         }
    });

    $("#close-button").click(function (event) {
        $("#message-container").hide();
        $("#to-box").hide();
        $("#recipient-box").val('');
        $("#subject-box").val('');
        $("#recipient-box").attr('placeholder', 'Recipients');
        $("#subject-box").attr('placeholder', 'Subject');
    });

    $("#recipient-container").click(function (event) {

        console.log("recipients clicked");
        $("#to-box").show();    

        $("#recipient-box").attr('placeholder', '');

        $(document).keydown(function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 32) {
                console.log("spacebar pressed!!");
             }
        });
    });

    $("#subject-box").click(function (event) {
        $(this).attr('placeholder', '');
    }); 
});
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everytime you click on #recipient-container, .keydown() will add an extra event handler to the document, without removing the existing ones.
The easiest solution here would be to remove the handler when you click on #close-button. Unbinding events can be done with .off().

```
$(document).off('keydown');
```